# Using an unordered_map of unordered_sets

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map

If I have an unordered map of unordered_sets indexed by strings, such as

```
static boost::unordered_map<std::string, boost::unordered_set<std::string> > UseMap;
```

I had a couple question about using this data structure. Is there anyway for me to insert a new value into the set indexed in the map without having to use a pointer to the set or reindex the map value?

Second question, I'm getting an unresolved external symbol error when I try to index into the map. As an example,

```
void AddUse(const std::string &character, const std::string& used)
{
    auto set = UseMap[character];
    set.insert(used);
    UseMap[character] = set;

}
```

I'm not sure why this is causing an unresolved symbol error, so any guidance there would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Any use of UseMap[character] causes the unresolved symbol error

Also added error code and source example

Full Class

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _SINGLEUSE_H_
#define _SINGLEUSE_H_
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
class SingleUse
{
public:
    void AddUse(const std::string& character, const std::string& used)
    {
        UseMap[character].insert(used);
    }

    bool HasUsed(const std::string &character, const std::string& used)
    {
        return false;//UseMap[character].find(used) != UseMap[character].end();
    }

    void ClearAll()
    {
        UseMap.clear();
    }
private:
    static boost::unordered_map<std::string, boost::unordered_set<std::string> > UseMap;
};
```

And the full error message:

Error   52  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class boost::unordered_map,class std::allocator >,class boost::unordered_set,class std::allocator >,struct boost::hash,class std::allocator > >,struct std::equal_to,class std::allocator > >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > > >,struct boost::hash,class std::allocator > >,struct std::equal_to,class std::allocator > >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > const ,class boost::unordered_set,class std::allocator >,struct boost::hash,class std::allocator > >,struct std::equal_to,class std::allocator > >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > > > > > > SingleUse::UseMap" (?UseMap@SingleUse@@0V?$unordered_map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$unordered_set@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$hash@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@boost@@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@boost@@U?$hash@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@4@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$unordered_set@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$hash@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@boost@@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@boost@@@std@@@2@@boost@@A)    G:\Documents\Programming Projects\KHMP\KHMP_Repo\KHMP\build\KHMP\KHMP\KHMPMain.obj

Comment: auto set should be auto& set, 'set' is a copy...

Comment: Could you tell **what** symbol is the problem?

Comment: The question still stands. Which **symbol** is the problem, now which statement. The error message mentions some symbol or symbols and having full text of the message including the symbol name might be an important hint to what is going on.

Comment: Why do you copy the set, insert into the copy and than copy the set back in? The `operator[]` returns a reference, so you can simply `UseMap[character].insert(used)`.

Comment: Is the symbol error a compiler or linker error? (Compiler errors have line numbers, linker errors don't.)

Comment: @mgiuca: "unresolved symbol" is always a linker error.

Comment: @Jan Hudec - That's what I was originally doing, but I wasn't sure if that would correctly insert/might have been the source of the unresolved symbol error. I didnt want to put the entire error code as it's quite lengthy, buty I'll add it as well as the code I'm using that generates this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First question, yes, it should be fine as long as you assign the result to a reference.

Do this:

```
boost::unordered_set<std::string>& set = UseMap[character];
```

Now `set` is a reference to a value in the map. (I'm not sure what `auto` gives you, so I put the type in full; you may be able to get away with using `auto`.) Any changes you make to `set` will be reflected in the map.

```
set.insert(used); // This updates the map, no need to write it back in.
```

Comment: auto & set = UseMap[character];

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the unresolved symbol is because I don't instantiate the static variable anywhere. I forgot you had to do that in C++, my mistake. Thanks for the help with the sets

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Don't static variables instantiate themselves? I thought only extern variables caused such a problem. What did you do to fix it?